# Хранение схожих данных в MSSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

У меня есть два объекта. У них есть много очень похожих полей, но также есть поля, которые есть только у одного из них. Мне нужно сохранить сохранить объекты такого формата в MSSQL. Создавать две отдельные таблицы не хочется, так как очень много полей повторяется, а также в будущем добавятся новые типы объектов с похожей структурой. 
Можно ли как то сохранять и получать объекты наиболее удобным способом ??? 
Ну например была идея сохранять общие поля в одной таблице а отличающиеся в другой.

Comment: Наследование вам не подходит?

Comment: а в MSSSQL разве есть нормальное наследование? Это чем то поможет при сохранении и получении данных?

Comment: Обязательно использовать MSSQL?

Comment: Наследование есть в EF

Comment: @СосланДзеранов у вас же entity framework, он возьмет наследование на себя: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. Поддерживается схемы "таблица на класс/тип" и "одна таблица на всю иерархию"

Comment: Наследование вполне можно реализовать в sql-server. См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/5045688 В EF оно реализовано: [TPH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618292(v=vs.113).aspx), [TPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618293(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сделать таблицу "Параметры", там список всех возможных параметров.
2. Создать таблицу "Объекты", там список объектов.
3. Создать таблицу "Объект-Параметр", где первичный ключ состоит из двух столбцов id_объекта из таблицы "Объекты" и id_параметры из таблицы "Параметры".

В такую структуру вы теперь какие угодно объекты сможете сохранить.

Comment: EAV на ровном месте применять не хорошо. он дико медленный при выборке, у него проблема с типами данных. По хорошему он необходим только в случае, если набор параметров не известен в момент разработки и может часто меняться в будущем.

Comment: @Mike это да. Если схема объекта часто меняется, то я бы рекомендовал NoSQL решение, всё же.

Comment: А если сделать так: иметь 1 объект и специфические данные хранить в виде JSON сериализованной строки.

Comment: @СосланДзеранов вы тогда мощь SQL теряете. MSSQL же не умеет искать по полям внутри Json'а.

Comment: Спасибо. Все понял)

Comment: @Suvitruf SQL Server умеет искать по полям внутри JSON: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @PashaPash ого, а раньше вроде нельзя было. Растут (: